# Adding collate support to Liquibase

Tags: liquibase

I'm using Liquibase to support MSSQL and Oracle implementations of a database.  The databases already exist.

I want to support collate on table columns. eg:

```
<createTable tableName="my_table">
  <column autoIncrement="true" name="id" type="int">
    <constraints nullable="false"/>
  </column>
  <column name="name" type="varchar(50)"/>
  <ext:column name="description" type="varchar(250)" collate="Latin1_General_CS_AS"/>
</createTable>
```

I want to process the new attribute for MSSQL only initially.  I've seen that the `modifySql` tag provides a means to support `collate` without using extensions.  I will want to do other similar changes as well and prefer the idea of extending Liquibase.

I've looked at other extensions, and cannot find an example of how to nicely extend existing statements.  I am thinking of doing the following:
Writing custom `CreateTableChange`, `CreateTableStatement` and `CreateTableGenerator` classes that extend the core `CreateTableChange`, `CreateTableStatement` and `CreateTableGenerator`.  Replacing the `generateStatements` method in `CreateTableChange` to create custom `CreateTableStatement` instances, and replacing `generateSql` in `CreateTableGenerator`.

I want to know whether this is the correct approach for extending existing change classes.  I'm concerned that I cannot call the base implementations of `generateStatements`and `generateSql`, but have to copy and paste the implementation, and it it starts to look like a new change type rather than an extension of an existing one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have much experience in writing extensions for liquibase yet, so I can't really tell you if this a good approach or if there is a better way.

But what I have noticed is that there are two packages: `liquibase.change` and `liquibase.change.core`. In the first package are abstract classes and interfaces like `AbstractChange`. I guess those are the ones that you are supposed to implement and extend when writing extensions. Therefore I would consider that package as being part of the API for extensions and thus to be pretty "stable".

The second package contains classes that liquibase uses itself. They might (will) get changed in future versions. 
So when you extend those classes your extension might have to change more often. I would guess that those classes are not part of an "extensions API". (I have not found any official documentation that proves this - it's just my observation.)

Other than that I'd say your approach should be doable.

Answer (score 0):

What works with Yaml is adding the colation to the data typem should also work with XML:

```
         - column:
              constraints:
                nullable: false
                primaryKey: true
              name: col1
              type: VARCHAR(32) CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_bin
```